# Count words in a sentence in C?

Tags: c, scanf

I am creating a program which counts the number of words in a given sentence, but when I run the program it gives 0 for every sentence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char wordCount(char sentence[]);
int main(void) {

        char wordsToCount[100];
        int numberOfWords;
        int i;

        printf("Word count \n");
        printf("========== \n");

        for (i=0; wordsToCount[i] != '\0'; i++) {

                printf("Text to be analyzed: ");
                scanf(" %s", &wordsToCount[i]);
        }

        /*numberOfWords = */wordCount(wordsToCount);

}

char wordCount(char sentence[]) {

        int wordsCount;
        int i;
        int count = 0;

        for (i=0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++) {

                if (sentence[i] == ' ') {

                        count++;
                }
        }

        printf("Word Count : %d \n", count);
}
```

Let's say if I enter:
Hello World. I should get 2, but the program keep asking me to input data again, but if I enter something like:
C is not that hard! 
I get 0.

```
Word count
==========
Text to be analyzed: C is not that hard
Word Count : 0

Word count
==========
Text to be analyzed: Hello World
Text to be analyzed: Text to be analyzed: Hello World
Text to be analyzed: Text to be analyzed:
```

Comment: In `for (i=0; wordsToCount[i] != '\0'; i++)` the array `wordsToCount[]` is uninitialised, hence you have *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: You should look at using the [`strtok`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) function to break up the words in your sentence.